Wired Connection is very slow in Ubuntu 24.04
Thank you for taking some of your time to fix my problem.
I recently moved from Windows to Linux.
I'm facing a very bad problem which is slow internet speed even though I'm using a wired connection. The cable is CAT 6E, my internet speed is 300 MB/s. I receive the full speed on Windows, but when I use Ubuntu it is between 30 to 42 MB/s. I tried to install the OS again and again, and still no good.
Here is the hardware list:
omar-pc                     
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: System Product Name (SKU)
    vendor: System manufacturer
    version: System Version
    serial: System Serial Number
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.3.0 dmi-3.3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=SKU uuid=a608db33-c6a3-568f-7654-244bfe566b9c
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: TUF B450M-PRO GAMING
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: Rev X.0x
       serial: 200670634802992
       slot: Default string
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 3802
          date: 04/28/2022
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 29
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 24GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
             product: CMW16GX4M1Z3200C16
             vendor: Corsair
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DIMM_A1
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
             product: Unknown
             vendor: Unknown
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DIMM_A2
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: [empty]
             product: Unknown
             vendor: Unknown
             physical id: 2
             serial: Unknown
             slot: DIMM_B1
        *-bank:3
             description: [empty]
             product: Unknown
             vendor: Unknown
             physical id: 3
             serial: Unknown
             slot: DIMM_B2
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 2c
          slot: L1 - Cache
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 2d
          slot: L2 - Cache
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 2e
          slot: L3 - Cache
          size: 32MiB
          capacity: 32MiB
          clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
          capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 2f
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 23.113.0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: AM4
          size: 2200MHz
          capacity: 4426MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdpru wbnoinvd arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif v_spec_ctrl umip rdpid overflow_recov succor smca sev sev_es cpufreq
          configuration: cores=8 enabledcores=8 microcode=141561889 threads=16
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Starship/Matisse Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: IOMMU
             product: Starship/Matisse IOMMU
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 0.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:00.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi ht cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 1.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:f6500000-f67fffff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 xHCI Compliant Host Controller
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi pm pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:48 memory:f67a0000-f67a7fff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@1
                   logical name: usb1
                   version: 6.08
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=10 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Audio device
                      product: Logitech G935 Gaming Headset
                      vendor: Logitech
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:4
                      logical name: card2
                      logical name: /dev/snd/controlC2
                      logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c
                      logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
                      logical name: input14
                      logical name: /dev/input/event2
                      version: 1.12
                      capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control usb
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: Gaming KB  Gaming KB  Keyboard
                      vendor: Gaming KB
                      physical id: 7
                      bus info: usb@1:7
                      logical name: input6
                      logical name: /dev/input/event5
                      logical name: input6::capslock
                      logical name: input6::numlock
                      logical name: input6::scrolllock
                      logical name: input7
                      logical name: /dev/input/event6
                      logical name: input8
                      logical name: /dev/input/event7
                      logical name: input9
                      logical name: /dev/input/event8
                      version: 30.02
                      capabilities: usb-1.10 usb
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=300mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:2
                      description: Mouse
                      product: G502 HERO Gaming Mouse
                      vendor: Logitech
                      physical id: a
                      bus info: usb@1:a
                      version: 27.03
                      serial: 126139533038
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=300mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2
                   logical name: usb2
                   version: 6.08
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-sata
                description: SATA controller
                product: 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                logical name: scsi0
                logical name: scsi1
                logical name: scsi4
                logical name: scsi5
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: sata msi pm pciexpress ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom emulated
                configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
                resources: irq:37 memory:f6780000-f679ffff memory:f6700000-f677ffff
              *-disk:0
                   description: ATA Disk
                   product: Fanxiang S101 51
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                   logical name: /dev/sda
                   version: 1E
                   serial: AA000000000000001150
                   size: 476GiB (512GB)
                   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                   configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=1a1365e4-431c-465e-8f7f-803c6bf24e83 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                 *-volume:0
                      description: reserved partition
                      vendor: Windows
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                      logical name: /dev/sda1
                      serial: 6b854589-8491-4886-b873-452c80116cda
                      capacity: 15MiB
                      capabilities: nofs
                      configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
                 *-volume:1
                      description: Windows NTFS volume
                      vendor: Windows
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                      logical name: /dev/sda2
                      version: 3.1
                      serial: a8b9bea0-ca2a-c44b-a78a-a91fe5e7dd70
                      size: 476GiB
                      capacity: 476GiB
                      capabilities: ntfs initialized
                      configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2023-04-12 20:51:26 filesystem=ntfs label=More Games name=Basic data partition state=clean
              *-disk:1
                   description: ATA Disk
                   product: KINGSTON SA400S3
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                   logical name: /dev/sdb
                   version: 1103
                   serial: 50026B7380D97E71
                   size: 447GiB (480GB)
                   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                   configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=52fec01c-a034-4ae5-b7b1-d175f4fe7941 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                 *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                      description: Windows FAT volume
                      vendor: mkfs.fat
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                      version: FAT32
                      serial: 8528-1e31
                      size: 297MiB
                      capacity: 299MiB
                      capabilities: boot fat initialized
                      configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
                 *-volume:1
                      description: EXT4 volume
                      vendor: Linux
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                      logical name: /dev/sdb2
                      logical name: /
                      version: 1.0
                      serial: 0cea2430-1ae5-4084-9d78-8fe0497f3856
                      size: 446GiB
                      capacity: 446GiB
                      capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                      configuration: created=2024-09-07 00:47:01 filesystem=ext4 label=kubuntu_2404 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2024-09-07 12:39:04 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,discard mounted=2024-09-07 14:38:32 name=kubuntu_2404 state=mounted
              *-disk:2
                   description: ATA Disk
                   product: ST500LM000-1EJ16
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
                   logical name: /dev/sdc
                   version: DEM3
                   serial: W3705JYF
                   size: 465GiB (500GB)
                   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                   configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=13464bf0
                 *-volume:0
                      description: Windows NTFS volume
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,1
                      logical name: /dev/sdc1
                      version: 3.1
                      serial: aa593565-1d52-e64b-b9a4-ffaf522db0ee
                      size: 465GiB
                      capacity: 465GiB
                      capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                      configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2022-06-05 18:30:01 filesystem=ntfs label=New Volume state=clean
                 *-volume:1
                      description: Windows NTFS volume
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,2
                      logical name: /dev/sdc2
                      version: 3.1
                      serial: 026e-ae44
                      size: 474MiB
                      capacity: 498MiB
                      capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                      configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2021-07-17 13:20:57 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
              *-disk:3
                   description: ATA Disk
                   product: ST500LM000-1EJ16
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0
                   logical name: /dev/sdd
                   version: DEM8
                   serial: W3735AFL
                   size: 465GiB (500GB)
                   capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                   configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=f25e4b02
                 *-volume
                      description: Windows NTFS volume
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: scsi@5:0.0.0,1
                      logical name: /dev/sdd1
                      version: 3.1
                      serial: a2c20c03-6b28-a24f-98c9-64cf768fa668
                      size: 465GiB
                      capacity: 465GiB
                      capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                      configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2022-04-22 23:23:13 filesystem=ntfs label=New Volume state=clean
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci msi pm pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=pcieport
                resources: irq:29 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:f6500000-f66fffff
              *-pci:0
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port
                   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                   version: 01
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci msi pm pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:33
              *-pci:1
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port
                   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
                   version: 01
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci msi pm pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:35 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:f6600000-f66fffff
                 *-network
                      description: Ethernet interface
                      product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                      vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                      logical name: enp4s0
                      version: 15
                      serial: 24:4b:fe:56:6b:9c
                      size: 1Gbit/s
                      capacity: 1Gbit/s
                      width: 64 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
                      resources: irq:34 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f6604000-f6604fff memory:f6600000-f6603fff
              *-pci:2
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port
                   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:04.0
                   version: 01
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci msi pm pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:36 memory:f6500000-f65fffff
                 *-nvme
                      description: NVMe device
                      product: KINGSTON SNV2S1000G
                      vendor: Kingston Technology Company, Inc.
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0
                      version: SBM02103
                      serial: 50026B7686281656
                      width: 64 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: nvme pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                      configuration: driver=nvme latency=0 nqn=nqn.2021-03.com.kingston:nvme:nvm-subsystem-sn-50026B7686281656 state=live
                      resources: irq:32 memory:f6500000-f6503fff
                    *-namespace:0
                         description: NVMe disk
                         physical id: 0
                         logical name: hwmon0
                    *-namespace:1
                         description: NVMe disk
                         physical id: 2
                         logical name: /dev/ng0n1
                    *-namespace:2
                         description: NVMe disk
                         physical id: 1
                         bus info: nvme@0:1
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
                         size: 931GiB (1TB)
                         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                         configuration: guid=66ff6b1b-a86a-408a-9cc5-51228505104f logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 wwid=eui.00000000000000000026b76862816565
                       *-volume:0
                            description: Windows FAT volume
                            vendor: MSDOS5.0
                            physical id: 1
                            bus info: nvme@0:1,1
                            logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p1
                            version: FAT32
                            serial: 32d5-6df5
                            size: 95MiB
                            capacity: 99MiB
                            capabilities: boot nomount fat initialized
                            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI system partition
                       *-volume:1
                            description: reserved partition
                            vendor: Windows
                            physical id: 2
                            bus info: nvme@0:1,2
                            logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p2
                            serial: a8791375-8f61-4b55-9285-1451461c1993
                            capacity: 15MiB
                            capabilities: nofs nomount
                            configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
                       *-volume:2
                            description: Windows NTFS volume
                            vendor: Windows
                            physical id: 3
                            bus info: nvme@0:1,3
                            logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p3
                            version: 3.1
                            serial: dccc0b7a-3548-1148-ba45-6c1014ccf931
                            size: 930GiB
                            capacity: 930GiB
                            capabilities: ntfs initialized
                            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2024-02-12 05:52:31 filesystem=ntfs name=Basic data partition state=dirty
                       *-volume:3
                            description: Windows NTFS volume
                            vendor: Windows
                            physical id: 4
                            bus info: nvme@0:1,4
                            logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p4
                            version: 3.1
                            serial: 34c9-29d1
                            size: 755MiB
                            capacity: 767MiB
                            capabilities: boot precious nomount ntfs initialized
                            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2024-02-12 05:58:49 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070 Ti]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                logical name: /dev/fb0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
                configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
                resources: iomemory:7f0-7ef iomemory:7f0-7ef irq:72 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:7fe0000000-7fefffffff memory:7ff0000000-7ff1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f6000000-f607ffff

Edit:
Windows Image
Linux Image
If you need more details, I'll do my best to provide them.

You say there is an error but in this massive list I do not see where you have shown the text of the error.

I edited the post and uploaded some images

The picture does nothing for the question you already said this. All it does is force anyone trying to help to have to load another screen. I still do not see the error.

May you please suggest way for me to help? Showing the images is all I can think about.

On Ubuntu Unity 24.04 running FIREFOX upload and download speeds are the same as on Win 11 Pro insider build.  PC is DELL Precision 7720 laptop.  ISP is Blue Stream Fiber.
John
